# Swagger issue => Additional properties not allowed: x=swagger=router-controller in swagger config

Tags: node.js, swagger

i am getting the issue in the swagger yaml format.
help me out to fix the below issue please.

Issue on Console:
    **Additional properties not allowed: x=swagger=router-controller in swagger config at: >paths//readinesstest/<**

```
path:

  /readinesstest/:
    x=swagger=router-controller: readinesstest/readinesstest
    get:
      tags: [readinesstest]
      operationId: prepareReadinessTest
      description: Prepating test based on the user status
      produces: [application/json]
      responses:
        '200':
          description: user readiness test insert
          schema: {$ref: '#/definitions/readinesstest'}
        '400':
           description: error
      parameters:
      - {$ref: '#/parameters/Bearer'}
  /user/:
    x-swagger-router-controller: users/users
    get:
      tags: [Users]
      operationId: getUser
      description: Gets the user
      produces: [application/json]
      responses:
        '200':
          description: User details returned
          schema: {$ref: '#/definitions/userInfo'}
      parameters:
      - {$ref: '#/parameters/Bearer'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `x=swagger=router-controller` with `x-swagger-router-controller`. Note the `-` characters instead of `=`.

Comment: May i know the purpose of  that line please?

Comment: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-node/blob/master/docs/controllers.md _"The `x-swagger-router-controller` Swagger extension element is used to specify the name of a controller file."_